# IrreduciblePolynomialQ[] = True; Factor[] doesn't do anything

Tags: polynomials

```
b[x_] := (((x^3) (y^2)) - ((3 x^2) (y)) - ((2 x) (y^3)) + (6 y^2))

fg = Factor[b[x]]
IrreduciblePolynomialQ[fg]
```

fg gives me (x^2-2y)y(-3+xy)

IrreduciblePolynomialQ[fg] gives False

Factor[fg] gives the same expression

What gives?

Comment: I’m not sure that I follow. Can you clarify what issue you have with these results?

Comment: The way I see it is that you've got a polynomial `bg` that is a product of nonconstant polynomials and therefore not [irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial).  Compare with `IrreduciblePolynomialQ /@ FactorList[b[x]][[All, 1]]`

Comment: So I have a polynomial, b[x]. After I execute fg = Factor[b[x]] I get a list of 3 terms, all of which seem unfactorable. However, when I execute IrreduciblePolynomialQ[fg] it returns false, meaning that the polynomial is reducible.

If I run Factor[fg] it returns the same terms.

Comment: `IrreduciblePolynomialQ` indicates that it factors, and `Factor` factored it. So the results are consistent.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want is to test the factors, but `Factor` gives the original polynomial in factored form, and that's reducible. To isolate the factors, use `FactorList`:

```
fl = FactorList[b[x]]
(* {{1, 1}, {x^2 - 2 y, 1}, {y, 1}, {-3 + x y, 1}} *)
IrreduciblePolynomialQ[fl[[2 ;;, 1]]]
(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that b[x] is NOT irreducible and therefore IrreduciblePolynomialQ[fg] returns False.